# Format time of input type time

Tags: reactjs, input

this is my input:

```
                <input
                  type="time"
                  className="start-time"
                  name="busi_start_time"
                  // value="Message"
                />
```

the screen will display as hh:mm (12h). How can I format it as HH:mm (24h)?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/input-type-time-y0vket

Comment: it can claim value in 24h format. However I want I can edit the input box in 24h format,

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to customize the display format of the HTML input time as you can see [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time):

> [...] uses a 12- or 24-hour format for inputting times, based on system locale

The behavior of the HTML input is defined by the browser and it seems that all browsers use the OS locale format to choose which display format to show to the user. So seeing a 12h or 24h format will depend on which is set on your OS.

A potential solution to force a display format is to use a library, but I guess that is outside of the scope of your question.

Comment: I would also add that it is usually ideal to display date and time using the user's locale to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me some lib to display time in React?

Comment: A good option would be https://github.com/react-component/time-picker, which is the library made and used by AntDesign. You can also use the AntDesign version which has built-in styles: https://ant.design/components/time-picker/. You can also look at other date picker librairies for React, and should mainly look at how popular the library is (number of stars) and how well maintained it is (recent releases).